# Xamarin Forms Rounded SearchHandler

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am testing new Shell Page in Xamarin Forms.
I am wondering if the search handler could be personalize, for example apply a rounded effect on search corner.
I tried to redefine the Template of SearchHandler but it just change the appearance of the result request of Search Handler (How suggestion are show to user).
Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: Please post minimal code snippet you tried so far.

Comment: The question is : Is it possible ? So if you can start answer this :) 

I cant share you snippet cause i dont know how to start.

I tried already : Effects (doesnt start on SearchHandler)
I tried Shell Renderer too (I think i can go further maybe the best way ?)
.

Answer (score 1):

I am back after severals test.

I find one way to do it easily.

For Top Navigation Bar in Shell App, there is a "Shell.TitleView" tag.

You can inside this tag define a personalize template.
So i deleted the "SearchHandler" and implement inside "Shell.TitleView" a Custom SearchBar with Rounded Corner.
It works pretty fine.
I can give you sample if needed.

If you know another way to do it, i will be a pleasure to test it.

Thanks

Comment: can you give us an example how did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's **impossible** to implement the Rounded `SearchHandler` if using `SearchHandler` in Shell Application .

**First** , about [SearchHandler appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/search#searchhandler-appearance) , there is no way to change the Round of it :

- `BackgroundColor`, of type Color, is the color of the background to the search box text.
- `CancelButtonColor`, of type Color, is the color of the cancel button.
- `CharacterSpacing`, of type double, is the spacing between characters of the SearchHandler text.
- `FontAttributes`, of type FontAttributes, indicates if the search box text is italic or bold.
- `FontFamily`, of type string, is the font family used for the search box text.
- `FontSize`, of type double, is the size of the search box text.
- `HorizontalTextAlignment`, of type TextAlignment, is the horizontal alignment of the search box text.
- `PlaceholderColor`, of type Color, is the color of the placeholder search box text.
- `TextColor`, of type Color, is the color of the search box text.
- `VerticalTextAlignment`, of type TextAlignment, is the vertical alignment of the search box text.

**Second** , if using [Shell Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers) also can not found `SearchBar` in `NavigationController` .

For example in iOS shell renderer :

```
public class CustomNavBarAppearanceTracker : IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ResetAppearance(UINavigationController controller)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetAppearance(UINavigationController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        //var seabar = controller.SearchDisplayController.SearchBar;
        controller.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("-----"+controller.NavigationItem.SearchController.SearchBar);
    }

    public void UpdateLayout(UINavigationController controller)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The Output is : `controller.NavigationItem.SearchController.SearchBar = null`

If not using `SearchHandler` , you can have a try with [Custom SearchBar Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) to implement it .

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
Yes i had already check if a corner radius property exist in Search Handler appearance.
So to conclude if i want to modify the corner radius i have to not use Search Handler and implement a custom search handler instead.
For searchbar the custom renderer is not necessary i could wrap it with Frame and apply a corner radius to the Frame.

Comment: @lalilulelo Yeah , that's also a good point to implement it. If works you can share solution here .

Comment: @lalilulelo Glad to see the solution , that's a good point to implement it !